# reCaptcha and loadbalancer on aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, load-balancing, recaptcha

Hello my application is using recaptcha from google, and when served only over nginx it works fine. Now we've setup everything to work behind load balancer on  aws and it gives invalid response and users can't register.

Anyone has suggestions why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to enable the Proxy Protocol setting to get the client's IP and sticky sessions so that application knows that session has been validated and it returns to the same app server.

> Proxy Protocol is an Internet protocol used to carry connection information from the source requesting the connection to the destination for which the connection was requested. Elastic Load Balancing uses Proxy Protocol version 1, which uses a human-readable header format.
>
> By default, when you use Transmission Control Protocol (TCP) for both front-end and back-end connections, your Classic Load Balancer forwards requests to the instances without modifying the request headers. If you enable Proxy Protocol, a human-readable header is added to the request header with connection information such as the source IP address, destination IP address, and port numbers. The header is then sent to the instance as part of the request.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/enable-proxy-protocol.html

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-sticky-sessions.html

Comment: Thanks man, we already figured it out but this is the anwser!